# remove identical values from 2 mysqli queries

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to make 2 mysqli queries. But if there are values in the second query that are Identical to the values yielded from the first query I want to exclude those values from the result set. What I have now only seems to work for 1 identical value. the rest of the identical values are shown. how should I change this? Thanks.

```
$query1 = $db->query("SELECT colTab1 FROM table1");

while ($result1 = $query1 ->fetch_assoc()) {
$query2 = $db->query("SELECT colTab2 FROM table2 WHERE colTab2 <> $result1[colTab1]");
     echo $result1['colTab1']."<br>";
}
  while ($result2 = $query2 ->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo $result2['colTab2']."<br>"; 
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can modify your second query as follows:

```sql
SELECT colTab2 FROM table2 WHERE colTab2 NOT IN (SELECT colTab1 FROM table1)
```

Or maybe you just want to select the [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/union.html) of the two tables (which will omit duplicates by default):

```sql
  SELECT colTab1 FROM table1
UNION
  SELECT colTab2 FROM table2
```

(Note that relying on `UNION` to omit duplicates between the two recordsets is not quite the same thing, as any duplicates that exist within each recordset will also be omitted; if that is a concern, one can `SELECT DISTINCT ... UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT ...` instead).

Comment: thanks for all the information. I used the NOT IN approach. It worked great.

Answer (score 1):

Just run one query; why bring back data from the database to filter on? Filter in the DB.

```
SELECT colTab2 
FROM table2 
WHERE colTab2 NOT IN (
    SELECT colTab1
    FROM   table1
)
```